# Define region between two curves

Tags: regions

I'm trying to define the region between two curves, `f[x]` and `g[x]`, I can easily find where they intersect:

```
f = Function[x, 12 x^2];

g = Function[x, 3 x^3];

p = {x, g[x]} /. DeleteDuplicates[Solve[g[x] == f[x], x, Reals]];

p1 = First[Take[p, 1]];

p2 = First[Drop[p, 1]];
```

From there I plot the curves:

```
plot = Plot[Evaluate@Through[{f, g}@x], {x, 0, 4}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 200}}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point@{p1, p2}}, 
  PlotLabels -> Automatic]
```

And all of that works fine, my problem is when I try and define the intersection of those two regions

```
rf = ImplicitRegion[y <= f[x], {x, y}];

rg = ImplicitRegion[y >=  g[x], {x, y}];

intersection = RegionIntersection @@ {rf, rg};

Region[rf, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 200}}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provide the coordinate bounds in the second argument of `ImplicitRegion`:

```
rf = ImplicitRegion[y <= f[x], {{x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 200}}]
```

> ```
> ImplicitRegion[y <= 12 x^2 && 0 <= x <= 4 && 0 <= y <= 200, {x, y}]
> ```

```
rg = ImplicitRegion[y >= g[x], {{x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 200}}]
```

> ```
> ImplicitRegion[y >= 3 x^3 && 0 <= x <= 4 && 0 <= y <= 200, {x, y}]
> ```

```
intersection = RegionIntersection @@ {rf, rg};

Region[#, AspectRatio -> 1] & /@ {rf, rg, intersection}
```

[image]

`RegionPlot` gives a better picture:

```
RegionPlot /@ {rf, rg, intersection}
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot[{rf, rg, intersection}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, im always missing little details like that, I appreciate the time you put into your answer.

Comment: @Wombles, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: @Wombles - Alternatively, use `rf = ImplicitRegion[y <= f[x] && p[[1, 1]] <= x <= p[[2, 1]], {x, y}]; 

rg = ImplicitRegion[y >= g[x] && p[[1, 1]] <= x <= p[[2, 1]], {x, y}];`

Comment: @BobHanlon, Thank you, i will give that a try as well!

Answer (score 3):

Just a direct way to do:

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[g[x] < y < f[x], {{x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 200}}];
ra = ImplicitRegion[y > f[x], {{x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 200}}];
rb = ImplicitRegion[y < g[x], {{x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 200}}];
rgns = {ir, ra, rb};
leg = First /@ rgns;
RegionPlot[{##}, PlotLegends -> leg] & @@ rgns
```

[image]